# Is using File.WriteAllText recommended over File.WriteAllLines for large files?

Tags: .net, file-io

I am outputing a list of strings into a regular text file.
These files may eventually be quite large. In other words, I may end up with large lists of strings to be flushed into disk.

I am assuming that it will be performance wise to do it using

`File.WriteAllText("myFile.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myListOfStrings))`

over

`File.WriteAllLines("myFile.txt", myListOfStrings)`,

since I will sum up all IO operations to one.

Am I right / will this really impact performance ?

---

**Edit**: Performance Analysis

I had barely ever played with VS Performance Analysis tool, but from the output I am getting (I chose Instrumentation over CPU bound since it sounds more conclusive to me to measure how much time did it spend in functions F1, F2...) - for a txt file with 120.000 lines WriteAllText is performing better by consuming some 7% less time to finish.

On the other hand, simply adding console outputs for stopwatch's start/stops shows WriteAllLines finishes in 0.20... seconds while WriteAllText in 0.30...

Comment: Profile it and find out.

Comment: @DanielMann: does profiling work only on release build configs (instead of debug) ?

Comment: If the files are quite large you should worry about your memory at `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myListOfStrings)`. So even if `WriteAllText` might be a little more efficient it could be the worse approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks for the insight, Tim.

Comment: WriteAllLines() does a much smarter job, it writes one line at a time to the file, writing Environment.NewLine() next.  That does not require any extra memory and does not make it any slower.  Your string.Join() call doubles the amount of memory taken by the string array.  Get further ahead by turning your string array into a Linq query or iterator.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks Hans for the important insight in the inner workings of `join()`.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit with using `WriteAllLines` is that you don't need to keep the complete string in memory before writing it to disk. Nor do you need to keep a complete materialized collection in memory, but can feed the IEnumerable.

Comment: Something along the lines what Tim Schmelter said. Thanks.